# Data framing summary statistics in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create a `XLSX` file containing the summary statistics (as in the `summary()` function), but I am not being able to create a reliable way to separate each value (mean, median, NA's etc.) into separate rows for each variable from the original variables. Since my database has more than 200 variables, I do need to create a more systematic way, instead of manually deleting words in my `XLSX`output.

After some research, I found some partial solutions, such as:

```
x1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df, summary, is.numeric)))
x2 <- data.frame(unclass(summary(df1)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x3 <- as.data.frame(apply(df,2,summary))
x4 <- data.frame(df1=matrix(df1),row.names=names(df1))
```

And what I need is something like this:

```
          y1      y2      y3       y4       y5
Min.    1.00    1.00    23.00    50.00    6.00
1st Qu. 31.75   3.75    30.50    57.25    11.75
Median  43.00   7.00    56.00    76.00    15.00
Mean    51.75   6.10    55.55    72.05    14.35
3rd Qu. 80.25   8.25    73.50    83.75    17.00
Max.    99.00   10.00    100.00  95.00    20.00
```

If someone would like to do some exercise, this database gives the same errors as my huge one:

```
x1 <- rpois(20,5)
x2 <- rexp(20,2)
x3 <- rexp(20,5); x3[1:10] <- NA_real_
x4 <- runif(20,5,10)
x5 <- runif(20,5,12)
df1 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

considering an example dataframe with columns y1, y2, ..., yn to summarise:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(y1 = rnorm(100),
           y2 = runif(100) ##, ... yn
           ) %>%
pivot_longer(starts_with('y'),
             names_to = 'variable',
             values_to = 'value'
             ) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    summarise(Min = min(value, na.rm = TRUE),
              Median = median(value, na.rm = TRUE) ##, ad libidum
              ) %>%
    pivot_longer(-variable) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = variable)
```

Generally, package {broom} offers convenient `tidy`ing of summaries into tibbles:

```
library(broom)
summary(1:10) %>% tidy
lm(displ ~ cyl, data = mpg) %>% tidy
```

or, if you want wide instead of long table format (as in your example):

```
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

summary(1:10) %>%
    tidy %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(),
                 names_to = 'stat',
                 values_to = 'value'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider casting `summary` results to `data.frame`, cleaning the columns, then `reshape` the output:

```r
summary_raw <- summary(df1)

# SPLIT Freq COLUMN AND SUBSET OUT NA ROWS
summary_long <- within(
  data.frame(summary_raw), {
    Var2 <- trimws(Var2)
    Agg <- trimws(sapply(strsplit(Freq, ':'), "[", 1))
    Num <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(Freq, ':'), "[", 2))
    rm(Var1, Freq)
  }
) |> subset(
  !is.na(Agg) & !is.na(Num)
)

# RESHAPE TO WIDE
summary_wide <- reshape(
  summary_long,
  idvar = "Agg",
  v.names = "Num",
  timevar = "Var2",
  direction = "wide",
) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

colnames(summary_wide) <- gsub(
    "Num\\.", "", names(summary_wide)
)
```

**Input**

```r
set.seed(43022)

x1 <- rpois(20,5)
x2 <- rexp(20,2)
x3 <- rexp(20,5); x3[1:10] <- NA_real_
x4 <- runif(20,5,10)
x5 <- runif(20,5,12)
df1 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

**Output**

```
> summary_wide
      Agg    x1       x2        x3    x4     x5
1    Min.  1.00 0.003004  0.009565 5.034  6.240
2 1st Qu.  3.00 0.086428  0.020734 6.903  7.323
3  Median  4.00 0.279303  0.035791 7.829  9.492
4    Mean  4.85 0.323793  0.098930 7.780  9.125
5 3rd Qu.  6.25 0.548857  0.067267 8.622 10.685
6    Max. 12.00 0.928066  0.523284 9.908 11.867
7    NA's    NA       NA 10.000000    NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a one-liner.

```
lapply(df1, summary) |> lapply(`length<-`, 6) |>  do.call(what=rbind) |> t() |> round(2)
#           x1   x2   x3   x4    x5
# Min.    1.00 0.03 0.03 5.23  5.48
# 1st Qu. 2.75 0.26 0.11 6.51  6.85
# Median  4.00 0.56 0.20 8.25  8.29
# Mean    4.55 0.57 0.24 7.94  8.29
# 3rd Qu. 6.00 0.70 0.28 9.43  9.57
# Max.    9.00 1.94 0.82 9.79 11.78
```

Just use `summary` in an `lapply`, adapt the `length`s to `6` to remove the `NA` display, `rbind`, `t`ranspose and `round` it. Works for numeric data as in your example.

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.